# Clarification on Azure SQL Database Backup plan (short term retention)

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-cost-calculation

I am confused with azure SQL database backup plan (short term backup retention).

As far as i understood,

1. In DTU purchasing model, no extra charge for backup storage, you only pay for redundancy type (such as LRS,ZRS)
2. In vCore purchase model, you will have to pay for backup storage.

am i right ?

does that mean , i will not have any backups if do not subscribe to backup storage in vCore ?

further, in azure pricing calculator, in vCore, General purpose option, you have two redundancy drop down options (i am not talking about long term retention plan) , what is the difference between them ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i will not have any backups if do not subscribe to backup storage in vCore ?

Yes, in *vCore*, if you do not allocate a storage account for backups, you will not be able to perform backup operations, either manually or automatically. If you believe you do not need backups, then you might be a *fool* ;), Azure will maintain access to your database according to the standard SLAs but the infrastructure will not provide a way for you to point-in-time restore the state of your database, only backups can adequately do that for you. But the storage costs are usually a very minimal component of your overall spend. Once the backup operation is complete you can download the backup for local storage and then clear the blob, making this aspect virtually cost free, but you will need *a* storage account to complete the backup process at all.

> in azure pricing calculator, in vCore, General purpose option, you have two redundancy drop down options

Are you referring to the Computer Redundancy:

[image: Azure SQL Db Compute Redundancy Options]

> **[Zone redundancy for Azure SQL Database general purpose tier](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-sql-blog/zone-redundancy-for-azure-sql-database-general-purpose-tier/ba-p/3280376)**
> The zone redundant configuration utilizes [Azure Availability Zones](https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/availability-zones/az-overview#availability-zones) to replicate databases across multiple physical locations within an Azure region. By selecting zone redundancy, you can make your serverless and provisioned general purpose single databases and elastic pools resilient to a much larger set of failures, including catastrophic datacenter outages, without any changes of the application logic. This configuration offers [99.995% availability SLA](https://%2099.995%25%20availability%20SLA) and RPO=0. For more information see [general purpose service tier zone redundant availability](https://aka.ms/documentationazuresqlzoneredundancyforgp).

In the other tiers, these redundancy modes are referred to as **LRS** (*Locally Redundant*) and **ZRS** (*Zone Redundant*). Think of this your choice on what happens when your data centre is affected by some sort of geological or political event that means the server cluster, pod or whole data centre is offline.

*Locally Redundant* offers redundancy only from a geographically local (often the same physical site). In general this protects from local hardware failures but not usually against scenarios that take the whole data center off-line. This is the minimal level of redundancy that Azure requires for their hardware management and maintenance plans.

*Zone Redundant* offers redundancy across multiple geographically independent zones but still within the same Azure *Region*. Each Azure availability zone is an individual physical location with its own independent networking, power, and cooling. ZRS provides a minimum of 99.9999999999% durability for objects during a given year.

There is a third type of redundancy offered in higher tiers: Geo-Redundant Storage (GRS). This has the same Zone level redundancy but configures additional replicas in other Azure regions around the world.

In the case of Azure SQL DB, these terms for *Compute* (So the actual server and CPU) have almost identical implications as that of *Storage Redundancy*. So  with regard to available options, the pricing calculator is pretty well documented for everything else, use the info tips for quick info and go to the reference pages for the extended information:

[image: Azure backup storage options]

The specifics are listed here: [Azure Storage redundancy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/azure/storage/common/storage-redundancy) but redundancy in Azure is achieved via replication. That means that an entire workable and usable version of your database is maintained so that in the event of failure, the replica takes the load.

---

A special feature of *replication* is that you can actively utilise the replicated instance for *Read Only* workloads, which gives us as developers and architects some interesting performance opportunities for moving complex reporting and analytic workloads out of the transactional data manipulations OOTB, traditionally this was a non-trivial configuration.

The **RA** prefix on redundancy options is an acronym for **Read Access**.

Comment: thanks for your detailed explanation, one more thing, if i set 200 GB of Backup storage, does that get allocated to the pool or database ? will i be charged per db ? if i have 2 DB then 200 GB's price * 2 ?

Comment: It doesn't work like that, storage is charged by _consumption_, so by total Gb. The calculator tool allows you to enter metrics to approximate expected usage and costs, but the _Backup Storage_ when implemented does not need to be dedicated to SQL, you can use the same storage container for other Azure resources if you want to, or you could store backups in an existing storage container.